# Class 'Image' not found in laravel 4

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I downloaded a website developed on laravel4 on my system and runing it on my localhost . Some of the pages are not working  .

When I am trying to upload an Image . following error is occurring.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
HELP
Class 'Image' not found
```

So I googled and got to know that I will have to add the intervention/image in my coomposer.json file i changed the code of json array from

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "1*"
    },
```

to

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "intervention/image": ""2.3.0""
    },
```

Then I did `composer update` and I am getting following error

Any leads ??

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\ideconnect>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for intervention/image 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by interv
ention/image[2.3.0].
    - intervention/image 2.3.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion fileinfo is missing from your system.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is fairly clear:

> the requested PHP extension **fileinfo** is missing from your system.

This means that the package you are trying to install relies on a PHP extension that your specific PHP installation does not have. This is fixable, but might be specific to your environment.

The first thing to do would be to check your `php.ini` and see if the extension is simply commented out. If you are using Windows, it might look like this inside `php.ini`:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

you should uncomment it like so:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

After doing this you will need to restart your webserver.

If that doesn't work, you will need to look for more info in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Comment: I followed your instaruction and I downloaded the file intervention/image and guzzel successfully still It says Image not found is there anything else I should do ?

Comment: can you confirm that the extension is indeed installed correctly? Run this command to check: `php -r "var_dump(extension_loaded('fileinfo'));"`